# Connecting to monero daemon

Tags: monerod

I'm having trouble connecting to monero daemon (running on my pc, on testnet) from my PHP script. I'm trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc` and getting `Unable to parse URI: :18082/json_rpc` (It's not an issue with code, i'm just trying to connect to node, nothing else). Is there any other parameter that I should put when starting node ?

Comment: Does the URI parser in whatever you're using know about ports ? Looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong port. testnet uses 28081 by default.